# Getting Bottom Left location of scroll able Screen

Tags: c#, winforms

**Description** Created a form in Winform C# app.

1. Added a panel (PBack) with dock type fill. (Scrollable)
2. Then added a picturebox(pbDraw) in panel(PBack) that height depends upon image size.

**I want to** add a control on the bottom left of the current screen view. (assume client scrolled down)

**What i tried**

1. `Rectangle rect = Screen.GetWorkingArea(pbDraw);`
   `ctrl.Top = rect.Top + rect.Height;`
2. `ctrl.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top + Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;`
3. `ctrl.Top = Screen.FromControl(pbDraw).WorkingArea.Top+ Screen.FromControl(pbDraw).WorkingArea.Height;`

**Issue** control is adding at top of pbDraw (0,0) and not on current screen bounds top.

[image]

Comment: First, you say "I want to add a control on **bottom** left of current screen view" then "... control is not on current screen bounds **top**". Do you want to stick this control to the screen's top or bottom? Do you want this component to stay in place during scrolling? Can you show us the picture?

Comment: I appologies its My mistake. Actually i want to display Control on bottom left of current bounds.

Comment: No problem, just fix your question. As far as I understand, you want to add this control at the bottom of an image, so the user will only see it when they scroll the image down. Am I correct? Again, some kind of a screenshot will be much appreciated.

Comment: I added Picture with Description. Hope it will be help ful
i want to add control to bottom left of current view.

Comment: When you add a control to a panel that is already scrolled then you have to adjust its Location.  Add the panel's AutoScrollPosition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, [`Control.Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.top?view=netframework-4.7.2) takes the scrolled view into account all by itself.

> Gets or sets the distance, in pixels, between the top edge of the control and the top edge of **its container's client area.**

So, you should be able to assign the coordinates relevant to the `pBack` and its client view:

```
ctrl.Top = pBack.Height - ctrl.Height;
```

Assuming that `ctrl` is a child of `pBack` this code should place it at the bottom of the current (scrolled) part of `pBack`

**UPDATE:**

As you said in the comments, `ctrl` is actually a child of `pbDraw`. In this case, you'll need to take the scrolling into account. For that, you can use [`Panel.VerticalScroll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.verticalscroll?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
//scroll position + panel height - control height
ctrl.Top = pBack.VerticalScroll.Value + pBack.Height - ctrl.Height;
```

If I were you, I'd add `ctrl` to the panel, on top of the picture box. This will make it easier to calculate offsets relative to the panel.

Comment: i am afraid to say its not working.
ctrl.Top = pBack.Height - ctrl.Height;

first time control is adding on exact position i want. but after scroll and click on button to add control again , its adding on same position as it added first time.

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar I've built a sample app and it works nicely. Are you sure that `ctrl` is a child of `pBack` (i.e. are you adding it like this: `pBack.Controls.Add(ctrl);`)?

Comment: not in pBack but adding in pDraw which is child of Pback and its dock fill
so :  Pback (Fill dock) -> Pdraw  and then PDraw.Controls,Add(ctrl)
PBack is scrollable and PDraw height depends on image height

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar Good! Have a nice day! :)